# TFS 2015 Build vNext recursive variable substitution

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Is it possible that the variable substitution is not recursive?

**Example1:**

Variable        Value

*SqlInstance*     (localDb)\mssqllocaldb

*DbCatalogName*   FooDb

*ConnStr*         data source=$(SqlInstance);initial catalog=$(DbCatalogName)$(Build.BuildId);

During the build the connection string substituted to: **data source=(localDb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=FooDb3211;**

This configuration works perfectly. But if i move the BuildId parameter to DbCatalogName variable it won't be substituted.

**Example2:**

Variable        Value

*SqlInstance*     (localDb)\mssqllocaldb

*DbCatalogName*   FooDb$(Build.BuildId)

ConnStr         data source=$(SqlInstance);initial catalog=$(DbCatalogName);

With this configuration the connection string is substituted to: **data source=(localDb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=FooDb$(Build.BuildId);**

So how can i chain variables with vNext?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the "DbCatalogName" variable contain the BuildID value, I recommend you to add an additional power-shell build step to set the  value of "DbCatalogName".

The code to set a variable value:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
```

Comment: But i don't need the BuildId value before build. And the Example 1 works fine and substitue the $(Build.BuildId) successfully.

Comment: @Kemy When you do use "ConnStr" variable? During deployment?

Comment: Yes, during the deployment. A powershell script gets the ConnStr and build a new, clean database for the test cases.

Comment: @Kemy  I just tried this with vNext build. It seems that for some tasks, like MSBuild, VSBuild, the variable value isn't get expanded. But for some tasks, like Powershell, CMD, the variable value can be expanded once.

Comment: Yeas, but only once. So i cannot chain multiple variables, because tha TFS only do the substitution once, and doesn't repeate if the subsituted value contains another variable placeholder.

Comment: All inputs are processed for variable references in the format $(varname) for all tasks in your definition.  Variable values are not processed for replacement as it could create an endless loop or we pick some arbitrary number of times to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Variable chaining seems to work with TFS 2015 Update 3.