# Can i use a predefined variable as the value of a custom variable in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am using **powershell scripts** for a lot of tasks in my Build and Release pipeline in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online).

These scripts require many parameters to be passed.

I was thinking of converting all the parameters into variables in Build and Release pipeline so that the tasks will be cleaner.

But many of my parameters already have predefined variables in them.

How can I use these values to create another variable?

If I define the variables as below, the predefined variables are not translated to their values.

**Example:**

`Blobname = Builds/$(Build.BuildNumber)/*`

`Use $(Blobname)` in my tasks.

How can I achieve the above in the configuration section of the release pipeline?

Edit:

I would like to add variables here as shown in the below screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Task Logging Commands [##vso[task.setvariable]value](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) which sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable.

Comment: I would like to make it easier for users to add the powershell script parameters by using the release pipeline variables. The above screenshot shows that in more details. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to expand the value of the variable recursively that there is some limitation on VSTS.

See Chris's comment in this case for details: [TFS 2015 Build vNext recursive variable substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266592/tfs-2015-build-vnext-recursive-variable-substitution)

> All inputs are processed for variable references in the format
>   $(varname) for all tasks in your definition. Variable values are not
>   processed for replacement as it could create an endless loop or we
>   pick some arbitrary number of times to replace.